# How do I detect that my attempt to send data via TLS secured socket has failed?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, ssl

This sample app creates a client-server connection via a TLS secured socket and sends some data over it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var listenerThread = new Thread(ListenerThreadEntry);
            listenerThread.Start();

            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

            var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
            socket.Connect("localhost", Port);

            var rawStream = new NetworkStream(socket);
            using (var sslStream = new SslStream(rawStream, false, VerifyServerCertificate))
            {
                var certificate = new X509Certificate(CertsPath + @"test.cer");
                var certificates = new X509CertificateCollection(new[] { certificate });
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("localhost", certificates, SslProtocols.Tls, false);

                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(sslStream))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("TEST");
                    writer.Flush();

                    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                }
            }

            socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            socket.Disconnect(false);
            Console.WriteLine("Success! Well, not really.");
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc);
        }
    }

    private static bool VerifyServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }

    static void ListenerThreadEntry()
    {
        try
        {
            var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
            listener.Start();

            var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            var serverCertificate = new X509Certificate2(CertsPath + @"\test.pfx");
            var sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false);
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(serverCertificate, false, SslProtocols.Tls, false);

            client.Close();  // terminate the connection

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(sslStream))
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("> " + line);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exc);
        }
    }
```

The trick is that the connection is terminated from the server side immediately after handshake. And the problem is that the client side knows nothing about it; I'd expect the client side to raise an exception when it tries to send data over the closed connection, but it doesn't.
So, the question is: how do I detect such cases, when the connection was interrupted and data didn't really reach the server?

Comment: It *looks* like the client side never closes the socket.  That's incorrect; errors may not be reported before closure.

Comment: @Kevin, it's just a repro application. The real application keeps the connection open for a long time. Apparently the client side raises an exception after a number of messages sent; the problem that it's happening some unknown time *after* the real disconnect, so I don't know what messages made it to the server and what not.

Comment: Oh.  Well, [you can't know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_generals_problem) exactly which messages made it.

Comment: @Kevin, TCP/IP is supposed to guarantee successful delivery, doesn't it?

Comment: Sure, but it's not magic.  It's running on top of an unreliable network, and can't tell the difference between "the connection dropped before my message arrived" and "the connection dropped after my message but before the other side was able to send a confirmation."  Additionally, TCP timeouts are relatively long, and you also have [Nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm) to contend with.

Comment: @Kevin, no magic required, just some confirmations. The problem of reliable delivery is inferior to the problem of two generals.

Comment: TCP does send confirmations.  The difficulty is that those confirmations can get lost just as easily as the original messages.  When the connection drops entirely, it is literally impossible to know whether unconfirmed messages have arrived or not.  It also bundles data up and sends it in batches, so your idea of a "message" is totally different from TCP's idea.

Comment: @Kevin, thanks for explaining the obvious, but this case is different. No delivery confirmation is lost, no even created. Plz don't sidetrack.

Comment: And how is the client supposed to *know that*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to know which packets have arrived under the TCP model.  TCP is a stream-oriented protocol, not a packet-oriented protocol; that is, it behaves like a bi-directional [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/7/pipe).  If you write 7 bytes, and then write 5 bytes, it's possible the other end will [just get 12 bytes all at once](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm).  Worse, TCP's reliable delivery only guarantees that *if* the data arrives, it will do so in the correct order without duplication or rearrangement, and that if the data does not arrive, it will be resent.

If the connection is broken unexpectedly, TCP does not guarantee that you will know exactly what data was lost, nor is it reasonably possible to provide that information.  The only thing the client knows is "I never [received an acknowledgement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Reliable_transmission) for byte number N [and presumably not for the previous n bytes either], despite resending them multiple times."  That is not enough information to determine whether byte N (and the other missing bytes) arrived at the server.  It's possible that they did arrive and then the connection dropped, before the server could acknowledge them.  It is also possible that they did not arrive at all.  TCP cannot provide you with this information, because only the server knows it, and you are not connected to the server any longer.

Now, if you close the socket *properly*, using [`shutdown(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shutdown) or the [.NET equivalent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.shutdown%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then data in flight will be pushed through if possible, and the other end will error out promptly.  Generally, we try to ensure that both sides agree on when to shutdown the connection.  In HTTP, this is done with the `Connection: Close` header, in FTP with the `BYE` command, and so on.  If one side shuts down unexpectedly, it may still cause data to be lost, because shutdown does not normally wait for acknowledgements.

Comment: "TCP does not guarantee that you will know exactly what data was lost, nor is it reasonably possible to provide that information." - however, it must guarantee that I know exactly what information was sent **and** its delivery was confirmed. Doesn't it?

Comment: While that information should theoretically be available, it's not immediately obvious to me whether .NET exposes it in a reasonable fashion.  Even calling flush should not wait for acknowledgements, because that could literally take seconds or even minutes over a sufficiently bad connection with a sufficiently large amount of data (Client sends 4000 bytes in multiple packets, server ACKs 1-200, client resends 201-4000, server ACKs 201-300, etc.).

Comment: As far as I understand, there are only 2 possible outcomes of an attempt to send data over TCP/IP: 1. Success (information is delivered and delivery confirmed). 2. Fail (information is delivered, but delivery confirmation is lost; or just never delivered at all. No way to tell one from another, and this is where the problem of 2 generals comes into play). Have I missed something?

Comment: That is *eventually* true of all data you send over TCP, but while your app is still running, there's a third state: The data is "in flight"; no ACK has been received but the stack is still actively trying to deliver or acknowledge it.  This corresponds to the same state as "fail" but before the timeout or retransmit limit has been reached.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.disconnect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you must call shutdown before calling disconnect or data can be lost.

Comment: Added shutdown. Still getting the "fake success" message.

Comment: This all is fine, but the TCP/IP client must not return "Success" status when the connection was interrupted by the other side unexpectedly.

Comment: And this all is fine too, but I'm still pretty sure that "don't receive any delivery confirmation, but report sending success to the caller" is not one of valid cases for a TCP/IP client.

Comment: Confirmation could take an unlimited amount of time. The other end can keep sending reset packets indefinitely.  Do you want to open yourself to a DOS attack?

Comment: If you haven't received confirmation within a specified period of time - just throw a timeout exception. Isn't it supposed to work in this way?

Comment: Nope.  You're supposed to send and receive an in-band command like the FTP `BYE` or the HTTP `Connection: Close`, not just randomly shut down the connection when you think you're done.

Comment: Any TCP/IP documentation to confirm that an unconfirmed attempt to send data can result in "success" status?

Comment: Try [this page](http://blog.netherlabs.nl/articles/2009/01/18/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable).

Comment: It seems you were right. But this hurts my feelings. TCP/IP designers should have provided means to check what data were delivered and confirmed.